# How can I select a result in mysql except a selected result in the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. I don't know how to solve it.

I have a Datatable like:

| bookingCode | status |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | NEW |
| ABC | CANCELED |
| DEF | CANCELED |

If I try to select `bookingCode` where `status = 'CANCELED'` I will get `ABC` and `DEF` as result. But `ABC` has a `NEW` Order. I want only `CANCELED` where is only one `bookingCode`. The result has to be only `DEF`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` or even a group by and filter in your having clause eg

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    bookingCode
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    status='CANCELED' AND bookingCode NOT IN (
        SELECT bookingCode FROM my_table WHERE status = 'NEW'
    );
```

| bookingCode |
| --- |
| DEF |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    bookingCode
FROM
    my_table t1
WHERE
    status='CANCELED' AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM my_table t2 
        WHERE status = 'NEW' AND t1.bookingCode = t2.bookingCode
    );
```

| bookingCode |
| --- |
| DEF |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT
    bookingCode
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    bookingCode
HAVING
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN status='CANCELED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) > 0 
    AND
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN status='NEW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) = 0 ;
```

| bookingCode |
| --- |
| DEF |

or only retrieve bookingcodes where status is cancelled

**Query #4**

```
SELECT
    bookingCode
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    bookingCode
HAVING
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN status='CANCELED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) = COUNT(bookingCode) ;
```

| bookingCode |
| --- |
| DEF |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mDoS5UeMJpvWPwwbdyzhC1/2)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery that finds booking codes that are different from `CANCELED`, and then use `NOT IN` to exclude those codes from the results.

```
SELECT bookingCode
FROM bookings
WHERE status = 'CANCELED'
AND bookingCode NOT IN (
    SELECT bookingCode
    FROM bookings
    WHERE status != 'CANCELED'
)
```